# Getting letters to enter an arraylist properly

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a Hangman game and need some help keeping track of letters already guessed.  I'm using an arraylist to keep track of the letters used. I need some help getting it to work properly. Here is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)   
{

    if(letter.equals(word.substring(i, i+1)))
    {
        //What happens if it does equal the letter
        newWord = newWord + letter + " ";
    }
    else
    {
        //what if it is NOT the letter
        newWord = newWord + "_ ";
    }

}

System.out.println(newWord);
System.out.println("Misses: " + letters);
```

this is the output with the word and number of letters printed as well:

```
team
4

_ _ _ _   
Enter a letter: t

t _ _ _ 

Misses: [t, t, t]
```

How do I get it so the arraylist won't save the "t" where it's missed when it's already used it?

The requested full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import TerminalIO.KeyboardReader; 

public class Hangman
{

  public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
  {
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Hangman.txt"));
    PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new File("Scorecard.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
    int random,wordSize;
    String word, letter, newWord="";

    //puts words into array and gets a random work
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        words.add(scan.nextLine());
    }


    random = (int)(Math.random() * (words.size()));

    //gets the size of the random word and print number of "_" needed
    word = words.get(random);
    wordSize = word.length();
    System.out.println(word);
    System.out.println(wordSize);

    for(int c = 1; c <= wordSize; c++)
        System.out.print("_ ");


    letter = reader.readLine("Enter a letter: ");

    for(int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if(letter.equals(word.substring(i, i+1)))
        {
            newWord = newWord + letter + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            newWord = newWord + "_ ";
        }

    }

    System.out.println(newWord);
    System.out.println("Misses:" + letters);

  }
}
```

Comment: You don't show your List in the code, but you check the contents of the List before you do an add.

Comment: share full code with us ..and explain more about what you need

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

For instance the [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) won't allow duplicates while the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) will.

Here there's a very good article about it: http://www.mkyong.com/java/what-is-the-different-between-set-and-list/

Answer (score 0):

For storing the letters that have already been used consider using a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29).

HashSets will only store one copy of anything added to it.